# Let $G=\mathbb{Z}\big /4\mathbb{Z}$ and $H=2\mathbb{Z}\big /4\mathbb{Z}$. Is $H$ isomorphic to $G\big / H$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-isomorphism, group-homomorphism, quotient-group

In Harvard Abstract Algebra lectures (video [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OMQUwhUJlnE&list=PLA58AC5CABC1321A3&index=9), minute 50:06), professor Gross shows the groups $G=\mathbb{Z}\big /4\mathbb{Z}$ and $H=2\mathbb{Z}\big /4\mathbb{Z}$ as an example in which a subgroup $H$ of a group $G$ does not map isomorphically to the quotient group $G\big/H$.

However, in order to convince myself I've tried to find an isomorphism between the two hoping to fail, but I am seeing there is a map that to me satisfies the conditions for an isomorphism:

$$\varphi: H\longrightarrow G\big/H$$

where these groups can be more explicitly written $H=\{0+4\mathbb{Z},\enspace2+4\mathbb{Z}\}$ and $G\big/H=\{ \underbrace{(0+4\mathbb{Z}) + H}_{=\{ 0+4\mathbb{Z}, \enspace 2+4\mathbb{Z}\}},\enspace \underbrace{(1+4\mathbb{Z})+H}_{=\{ 1+4\mathbb{Z}, \enspace 3+4\mathbb{Z}\}}\}$. Which I define as the map that sends the elements: $$0+4\mathbb{Z}\longmapsto (0+4\mathbb{Z}) + H \\ 2+4\mathbb{Z}\longmapsto (1+4\mathbb{Z}) + H$$

and, which the explicit definition I give is bijective, and which I verify is homomorphic. For example:

$\varphi( \underbrace{\left(0+4\mathbb{Z}\right) + \left(2+4\mathbb{Z}\right)}_{=(0+2)+4\mathbb{Z}=2+4\mathbb{Z}}) = \varphi(2+4\mathbb{Z})=(1+4\mathbb{Z}) + H = \left(       
\left(0+4\mathbb{Z}\right) + \left(1+4\mathbb{Z}\right)\right)+H=      
\underbrace{\left(0+4\mathbb{Z}\right) + H}_{\varphi(0+4\mathbb{Z})} + \underbrace{\left(1+4\mathbb{Z}\right) + H}_{\varphi(2+4\mathbb{Z})}$

The professor claims that every of the two elements of $H$ map to $H$, that none go to the other coset.

Could someone please help me to clarify this?

Comment: There is a difference between whether $H$ is isomorphic to $G/H$ via *some* isomorphism (yes, they are), and whether $H$ is mapped isomorphically onto $G/H$ via *the canonical projections* that sends $g\in G$ to the element $gH$ of $G/H$. The answer to the latter is "no". Your map is not the canonical projection, which is what the example is about: a subgroup of $G$ that does not map isomorphically onto its image in $G/H$ *via the canonical projection map*.

Comment: In short: there is a difference between the questions "Is the subgroup $A$ isomorphic to the group $B$?" and "Is the subgroup $A$ isomorphic to its image in $B$ under the morphism $f\colon G\to B$?"